# Adding file type to ack permanently

Tags: file-types, ack

I've recently learned how to [let ack support more filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3870611/62120) (adding the following to `.ackrc`):

```
--type-add
latte=.latte
```

Unfortunately, that produces an info line on every ack search I use, even ones with 0 results.

```
$ ack --latte dump
ack: --type-add: Type "latte" does not exist, creating with ".latte" ...
```

Is there a way to make this a more permanent addition? (i.e. get rid of this info line) This looks to me like it's adding this new type on every ack call. Is it a problem with my installation of ack?

<sub>I'm on Mac OS X 10.5.8 with ack 1.92 (Running under Perl 5.10.1)</sub>

Comment: Regarding 10.6->10.5.8: I really have no idea why I wrote 10.6, I've always had 10.5.8... And when I realized it, I changed it...

Comment: Odd revision history: @Mehper started editing within the 5 minute grace period, and then (after Mehper *started*, but before he *saved*) Martin changed "10.6" to "10.5.8". Next, the change was undone when Mehper saved the edits to the (then) older text — which for the history was still the same revision due to the grace period, hence listing Mehper as changing the version. If you're bothered about this, then consider voting for [After saving, alert when post was meanwhile saved by someone else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20658/after-saving-alert-when-post-was-meanwhile-saved).

Comment: +1 I was using --type-set following the documentation but had no idea the types should be in a new line

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems to me that [the documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ack/ack-base#Defining_your_own_types) claims you need `--type-set` instead:

```
--type-set
latte=.latte
```

Whereas `--type-add` is for, emphasis mine:

> Files with the given EXTENSION(s) are recognized as being of (**the existing**) type TYPE.

Comment: +1 It also says "If you want to define a new type, or completely redefine an existing type, then use **`--type-set`**."

Comment: Hmmm... I've read that section quite a few times, but I did not realize/understand, that I suits my needs! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... `ack` is basically a Perl script... which is quite easy to edit:

```
%mappings = (
    actionscript => [qw( as mxml )],
    ada         => [qw( ada adb ads )],
...
    latte       => [qw( latte )],
...
    yaml        => [qw( yaml yml )],
    xml         => [qw( xml dtd xslt ent )],
);
```

But still, is there another solution to this?

Comment: If you edit ack-grep itself you lose the benefit of subsequent upgrades because upgrading would overwrite your changes. The configuration can be done in .ackrc which is a superior solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create or edit `.ackrc` in your `$HOME` directory and add `--type-add=cpp:ext:inl`.

This adds the file **ext**ension `inl` as a match for the existing type "cpp".

`~/.ackrc`:

```
# C++
--type-add=cpp:ext:inl
```

Usage:

```sh
ack --cpp Foo
```

In addition to match type `ext` for file extension, there is also `is` for exact filename match, `match` for regex match, and `firstlinematch` (also a regex, but matches against the first line of each file).